# In HTML5, where is the line between WebGL drawing an non WebGL drawing?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl

The HTML canvas element is impressive and what people are doing with it is mind blowing. When I study the javascript that developers use, it's not always apparent if what I'm seeing qualifies for the term "WebGL" or not. Where is the line drawn between what is and is not WebGL?

Comment: just guessing, but maybe see if the code shows GLSL shaders? otherwise, i'm curious myself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's WebGL if they're using a `WebGLRenderingContext`. See: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/

Example 1 from that document shows:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is two types of use of `<canvas>` element right now: **2D** and **WebGL**. Those called `context`.

You get context using `canvas.getContext('yourContextHere');`. The easiest way to identify which context is used, just search for `getContext` and see what is used as first argument.

There is one `2d` context, while there is many variations of `webgl`, like `experimental-webgl`, `webkit-3d` and few others, but they will usually contain or `webgl` or `3d` word in it.

Another big difference is dimensions, 2d context is obviously only 2 dimensions, still it is possible to do some math with matrices and simulate 3 dimensions, this technique sometimes is used in order to draw something simple with feel of 3d. But that is rare.

WebGL is based OpenGL ES 2.0 and has own functionality, totally different from 2d context. So if you learn some of it then it will be very easy to distinguish between them.